# Datestore usage still full after deleting it all

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I used the delete method to delete all of my datastore "tables" in the [Datastore admin](https://appengine.google.com/datastore/admin) page, but the usage on the dashboard for datastore is still the same as it was before the delete. How long should I need to wait until it is updated? I thought the dashboard would have updated this morning once the quotes are reset, but they haven't.

Thanks,
Ankur

Comment: Statistics are updated once a day.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait another 24 hours and see what happens.